# Android 2.2 and "Bad address family" on Socket Connect

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have a fairly simple game that works perfectly on every version now up through 2.1, but with the new 2.2 (Froyo) release I am unable to create a socket.  I am using the mina package for nio, and get this exception:

> W/System.err(  263): **java.net.SocketException: Bad address family**
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl(Native Method)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(OSNetworkSystem.java:115)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:272)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.PipeImpl$SinkChannelImpl.finishConnect(PipeImpl.java:164)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.PipeImpl.(PipeImpl.java:48)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:51)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SelectorImpl.(SelectorImpl.java:141)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SelectorProviderImpl.openSelector(SelectorProviderImpl.java:58)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:48)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketConnector.startupWorker(SocketConnector.java:248)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:210)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:137)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.mina.common.support.BaseIoConnector.connect(BaseIoConnector.java:40)

Later in the log, usually immediately following I get this:

> W/System.err(  263): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.harmony.nio.internal.SelectorImpl.wakeup(SelectorImpl.java:418)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:222)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketConnector.connect(SocketConnector.java:137)
>   W/System.err(  263):    at org.apache.mina.common.support.BaseIoConnector.connect(BaseIoConnector.java:40)

I have done all the googling and looking around I can think of and found nothing.  The closest I have come seems to be an old JDK bug with ipv6 support on XP and Vista machines (I'm running Vista).  Recommendations included disabling ipv6 (that did not work) and disabling ipv4 and leaving ipv6 (will not work for me as my router and ISP don't support it and so could not test anyway).

Any thoughts, suggestions, things I have not tried?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: can you post your Socket setup code?

Comment: Hi Roman, I'm using a gaming API, but I should be able to get the code.  Interestingly, not what I am using, but others seem to be having the same problem:

http://www.smartfoxserver.com/forums/viewtopic.php?p=30837&sid=74947ea6a890930771eab7fc36ab41ec

I'll see if I can find the code that sets things up and post it here.

-- Josh

Comment: A quick update.  In the process of trying to find the code causing the problem in the mina package, I just decided it would be easier to use a different stack altogether.  In changing it out to a semi custom solution using standard java.net.Socket stuff - everything works fine now.  Suppose this will not help someone stuck without this option, but it worked for me - so moving on.

-- Josh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this was a bug and has been fixed: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9431

you should be very careful with the java.net.preferIPv6Addresses workaround, because there are devices and networks where you do want IPv6.

(and, as the original poster found, if you *can* use io rather than nio, you generally *should*.)

Comment: Given that I really do want to use NIO, do you know if it's possible to detect if the device has IPV6 support or not, and only apply the workaround fix if no IPV6 support is possible? 

Alternatively, wait until you've experienced the exception and then apply the workaround and try again?

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to Josh...
I could get the andswer for this problem at the link above

using this code before opening a Selector

==> System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "false");

i can pass the problem...

Comment: Works for me. My environment is emulator running on Ubuntu 10.4 system.

Comment: this is a dangerous workaround on real devices. please vote up _my_ answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are right. I posted this problem to google groups and the comment was "the emulator doesn't support IPv6". Here is the link
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9431

Do you know why application should think it's device can support iPv6 or not? I think java application programmers don't need to know that.