# VM aborting Getting error while running in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, cordova

I am using phonegap with socket programming.

When I check on emulator I am  getting  **VM aborting** error.

I am just calling my server and checking it to my emulator.

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.test;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        appView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebSocketFactory(appView), "WebSocketFactory");


    }



}

---------------------------------------------------------------------
package com.example.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;


    public class WebSocket implements Runnable {

        /**
         * Enum for WebSocket Draft
         */
        public enum Draft {
            DRAFT75, DRAFT76
        }

        // //////////////// CONSTANT
        /**
         * The connection has not yet been established.
         */
        public final static int WEBSOCKET_STATE_CONNECTING = 0;
        /**
         * The WebSocket connection is established and communication is possible.
         */
        public final static int WEBSOCKET_STATE_OPEN = 1;
        /**
         * The connection is going through the closing handshake.
         */
        public final static int WEBSOCKET_STATE_CLOSING = 2;
        /**
         * The connection has been closed or could not be opened.
         */
        public final static int WEBSOCKET_STATE_CLOSED = 3;

        /**
         * An empty string
         */
        private static String BLANK_MESSAGE = "";
        /**
         * The javascript method name for onOpen event.
         */
        private static String EVENT_ON_OPEN = "onopen";
        /**
         * The javascript method name for onMessage event.
         */
        private static String EVENT_ON_MESSAGE = "onmessage";
        /**
         * The javascript method name for onClose event.
         */
        private static String EVENT_ON_CLOSE = "onclose";
        /**
         * The javascript method name for onError event.
         */
        private static String EVENT_ON_ERROR = "onerror";
        /**
         * The default port of WebSockets, as defined in the spec.
         */
        public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 80;
        /**
         * The WebSocket protocol expects UTF-8 encoded bytes.
         */
        public static final String UTF8_CHARSET = "UTF-8";
        /**
         * The byte representing Carriage Return, or \r
         */
        public static final byte DATA_CR = (byte) 0x0D;
        /**
         * The byte representing Line Feed, or \n
         */
        public static final byte DATA_LF = (byte) 0x0A;
        /**
         * The byte representing the beginning of a WebSocket text frame.
         */
        public static final byte DATA_START_OF_FRAME = (byte) 0x00;
        /**
         * The byte representing the end of a WebSocket text frame.
         */
        public static final byte DATA_END_OF_FRAME = (byte) 0xFF;

        // //////////////// INSTANCE Variables
        /**
         * The WebView instance from Phonegap DroidGap
         */
        private final WebView appView;
        /**
         * The unique id for this instance (helps to bind this to javascript events)
         */
        private String id;
        /**
         * The URI this client is supposed to connect to.
         */
        private URI uri;
        /**
         * The port of the websocket server
         */
        private int port;
        /**
         * The Draft of the WebSocket protocol the Client is adhering to.
         */
        private Draft draft;
        /**
         * The <tt>SocketChannel</tt> instance to use for this server connection.
         * This is used to read and write data to.
         */
        private SocketChannel socketChannel;
        /**
         * The 'Selector' used to get event keys from the underlying socket.
         */
        private Selector selector;
        /**
         * Keeps track of whether or not the client thread should continue running.
         */
        private boolean running;
        /**
         * Internally used to determine whether to recieve data as part of the
         * remote handshake, or as part of a text frame.
         */
        private boolean handshakeComplete;
        /**
         * The 1-byte buffer reused throughout the WebSocket connection to read
         * data.
         */
        private ByteBuffer buffer;
        /**
         * The bytes that make up the remote handshake.
         */
        private ByteBuffer remoteHandshake;
        /**
         * The bytes that make up the current text frame being read.
         */
        private ByteBuffer currentFrame;
        /**
         * Queue of buffers that need to be sent to the client.
         */
        private BlockingQueue<ByteBuffer> bufferQueue;
        /**
         * Lock object to ensure that data is sent from the bufferQueue in the
         * proper order
         */
        private Object bufferQueueMutex = new Object();
        /**
         * Number 1 used in handshake
         */
        private int number1 = 0;
        /**
         * Number 2 used in handshake
         */
        private int number2 = 0;
        /**
         * Key3 used in handshake
         */
        private byte[] key3 = null;
        /**
         * The readyState attribute represents the state of the connection.
         */
        private int readyState = WEBSOCKET_STATE_CONNECTING;

        private final WebSocket instance;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         * 
         * Note: this is protected because it's supposed to be instantiated from {@link WebSocketFactory} only.
         * 
         * @param appView
         *            {@link android.webkit.WebView}
         * @param uri
         *            websocket server {@link URI}
         * @param draft
         *            websocket server {@link Draft} implementation (75/76)
         * @param id
         *            unique id for this instance
         */
        protected WebSocket(WebView appView, URI uri, Draft draft, String id) {
            this.appView = appView;
            this.uri = uri;
            this.draft = draft;

            // port
            port = uri.getPort();
            if (port == -1) {
                port = DEFAULT_PORT;
            }

            // Id
            this.id = id;

            this.bufferQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer>();
            this.handshakeComplete = false;
            this.remoteHandshake = this.currentFrame = null;
            this.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);

            this.instance = this;
        }

        // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // /////////////////////////// WEB SOCKET API Methods
        // ///////////////////////////////////
        // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /**
         * Starts a new Thread and connects to server
         * 
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public Thread connect() throws IOException {
            this.running = true;
            this.readyState = WEBSOCKET_STATE_CONNECTING;
            // open socket
            socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
            socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            // set address
            socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(uri.getHost(), port));
            // start a thread to make connection

            // More info:
            // http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/45a8b53e9bf60d82
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879455/android-2-2-and-bad-address-family-on-socket-connect
            System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
            System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "false");

            selector = Selector.open();
            socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
            Log.v("websocket", "Starting a new thread to manage data reading/writing");

            Thread th = new Thread(this);
            th.start();
            // return thread object for explicit closing, if needed
            return th;
        }

        public void run() {
            while (this.running) {
                try {
                    _connect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    this.onError(e);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Closes connection with server
         */
        public void close() {
            this.readyState = WebSocket.WEBSOCKET_STATE_CLOSING;

            // close socket channel
            try {
                this.socketChannel.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                this.onError(e);
            }
            this.running = false;
            selector.wakeup();

            // fire onClose method
            this.onClose();

            this.readyState = WebSocket.WEBSOCKET_STATE_CLOSED;
        }

        /**
         * Sends <var>text</var> to server
         * 
         * @param text
         *            String to send to server
         */
        public void send(final String text) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (instance.readyState == WEBSOCKET_STATE_OPEN) {
                        try {
                            instance._send(text);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            instance.onError(e);
                        }
                    } else {
                        instance.onError(new NotYetConnectedException());
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        /**
         * Called when an entire text frame has been received.
         * 
         * @param msg
         *            Message from websocket server
         */
        public void onMessage(final String msg) {
            appView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    appView.loadUrl(buildJavaScriptData(EVENT_ON_MESSAGE, msg));
                }
            });
        }

        public void onOpen() {
            appView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    appView.loadUrl(buildJavaScriptData(EVENT_ON_OPEN, BLANK_MESSAGE));
                }
            });
        }

        public void onClose() {
            appView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    appView.loadUrl(buildJavaScriptData(EVENT_ON_CLOSE, BLANK_MESSAGE));
                }
            });
        }

        public void onError(final Throwable t) {
            appView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    appView.loadUrl(buildJavaScriptData(EVENT_ON_ERROR, t.getMessage()));
                }
            });
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        /**
         * @return the readyState
         */
        public int getReadyState() {
            return readyState;
        }

        /**
         * Builds text for javascript engine to invoke proper event method with
         * proper data.
         * 
         * @param event
         *            websocket event (onOpen, onMessage etc.)
         * @param msg
         *            Text message received from websocket server
         * @return
         */
        private String buildJavaScriptData(String event, String msg) {
            String _d = "javascript:WebSocket." + event + "(" + "{" + "\"_target\":\"" + id + "\"," + "\"data\":'" + msg.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")
                    + "'" + "}" + ")";
            return _d;
        }

        // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // /////////////////////////// WEB SOCKET Internal Methods
        // //////////////////////////////
        // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private boolean _send(String text) throws IOException {
            if (!this.handshakeComplete) {
                throw new NotYetConnectedException();
            }
            if (text == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Cannot send 'null' data to a WebSocket.");
            }

            // Get 'text' into a WebSocket "frame" of bytes
            byte[] textBytes = text.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET.toString());
            ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(textBytes.length + 2);
            b.put(DATA_START_OF_FRAME);
            b.put(textBytes);
            b.put(DATA_END_OF_FRAME);
            b.rewind();

            // See if we have any backlog that needs to be sent first
            if (_write()) {
                // Write the ByteBuffer to the socket
                this.socketChannel.write(b);
            }

            // If we didn't get it all sent, add it to the buffer of buffers
            if (b.remaining() > 0) {
                if (!this.bufferQueue.offer(b)) {
                    throw new IOException("Buffers are full, message could not be sent to"
                            + this.socketChannel.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
                }
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        // actual connection logic
        private void _connect() throws IOException {
            // Continuous loop that is only supposed to end when "close" is called.

            selector.select();
            Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> i = keys.iterator();

            while (i.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = i.next();
                i.remove();
                if (key.isConnectable()) {
                    if (socketChannel.isConnectionPending()) {
                        socketChannel.finishConnect();
                    }
                    socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                    _writeHandshake();
                }
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    try {
                        _read();
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsa) {
                        this.onError(nsa);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private void _writeHandshake() throws IOException {
            String path = this.uri.getPath();
            if (path.indexOf("/") != 0) {
                path = "/" + path;
            }

            String host = uri.getHost() + (port != DEFAULT_PORT ? ":" + port : "");
            String origin = "*"; // TODO: Make 'origin' configurable
            String request = "GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" + "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n" + "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                    + "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + "Origin: " + origin + "\r\n";

            // Add random keys for Draft76
            if (this.draft == Draft.DRAFT76) {
                request += "Sec-WebSocket-Key1: " + this._randomKey() + "\r\n";
                request += "Sec-WebSocket-Key2: " + this._randomKey() + "\r\n";
                request += "\r\n";
                this.key3 = new byte[8];
                (new Random()).nextBytes(this.key3);

                // Convert to bytes early so last eight bytes don't get jacked
                byte[] bRequest = request.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET);

                byte[] bToSend = new byte[bRequest.length + 8];

                // Copy in the Request bytes
                System.arraycopy(bRequest, 0, bToSend, 0, bRequest.length);

                // Now tack on key3 bytes
                System.arraycopy(this.key3, 0, bToSend, bRequest.length, this.key3.length);

                // Now we can send all keys as a single frame
                _write(bToSend);
                return;
            }

            request += "\r\n";
            _write(request.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET));
        }

        private boolean _write() throws IOException {
            synchronized (this.bufferQueueMutex) {
                ByteBuffer buffer = this.bufferQueue.peek();
                while (buffer != null) {
                    this.socketChannel.write(buffer);
                    if (buffer.remaining() > 0) {
                        return false; // Didn't finish this buffer. There's more to
                        // send.
                    } else {
                        this.bufferQueue.poll(); // Buffer finished. Remove it.
                        buffer = this.bufferQueue.peek();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        private void _write(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
            this.socketChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
        }

        private void _read() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            this.buffer.rewind();

            int bytesRead = -1;
            try {
                bytesRead = this.socketChannel.read(this.buffer);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }

            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                close();
            } else if (bytesRead > 0) {
                this.buffer.rewind();

                if (!this.handshakeComplete) {
                    _readHandshake();
                } else {
                    _readFrame();
                }
            }
        }

        private void _readFrame() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            byte newestByte = this.buffer.get();

            if (newestByte == DATA_START_OF_FRAME) { // Beginning of Frame
                this.currentFrame = null;

            } else if (newestByte == DATA_END_OF_FRAME) { // End of Frame
                String textFrame = null;
                // currentFrame will be null if END_OF_FRAME was send directly after
                // START_OF_FRAME, thus we will send 'null' as the sent message.
                if (this.currentFrame != null) {
                    textFrame = new String(this.currentFrame.array(), "ISO-8859-1");
                }
                // fire onMessage method
                this.onMessage(textFrame);

            } else { // Regular frame data, add to current frame buffer
                ByteBuffer frame = ByteBuffer.allocate((this.currentFrame != null ? this.currentFrame.capacity() : 0)
                        + this.buffer.capacity());
                if (this.currentFrame != null) {
                    this.currentFrame.rewind();
                    frame.put(this.currentFrame);
                }
                frame.put(newestByte);
                this.currentFrame = frame;
            String textFrame = new String(this.currentFrame.array(),"ISO-8859-1");

                this.onMessage(textFrame);
            }
        }

        private void _readHandshake() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            ByteBuffer ch = ByteBuffer.allocate((this.remoteHandshake != null ? this.remoteHandshake.capacity() : 0)
                    + this.buffer.capacity());
            if (this.remoteHandshake != null) {
                this.remoteHandshake.rewind();
                ch.put(this.remoteHandshake);
            }
            ch.put(this.buffer);
            this.remoteHandshake = ch;
            byte[] h = this.remoteHandshake.array();
            // If the ByteBuffer contains 16 random bytes, and ends with
            // 0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A (or two CRLFs), then the client
            // handshake is complete for Draft 76 Client.
            if ((h.length >= 20 && h[h.length - 20] == DATA_CR && h[h.length - 19] == DATA_LF
                    && h[h.length - 18] == DATA_CR && h[h.length - 17] == DATA_LF)) {
                _readHandshake(new byte[] { h[h.length - 16], h[h.length - 15], h[h.length - 14], h[h.length - 13],
                        h[h.length - 12], h[h.length - 11], h[h.length - 10], h[h.length - 9], h[h.length - 8],
                        h[h.length - 7], h[h.length - 6], h[h.length - 5], h[h.length - 4], h[h.length - 3],
                        h[h.length - 2], h[h.length - 1] });

                // If the ByteBuffer contains 8 random bytes,ends with
                // 0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A (or two CRLFs), and the response
                // contains Sec-WebSocket-Key1 then the client
                // handshake is complete for Draft 76 Server.
            } else if ((h.length >= 12 && h[h.length - 12] == DATA_CR && h[h.length - 11] == DATA_LF
                    && h[h.length - 10] == DATA_CR && h[h.length - 9] == DATA_LF)
                    && new String(this.remoteHandshake.array(), UTF8_CHARSET).contains("Sec-WebSocket-Key1")) {// ************************
                _readHandshake(new byte[] { h[h.length - 8], h[h.length - 7], h[h.length - 6], h[h.length - 5],
                        h[h.length - 4], h[h.length - 3], h[h.length - 2], h[h.length - 1] });

                // Consider Draft 75, and the Flash Security Policy
                // Request edge-case.
            } else if ((h.length >= 4 && h[h.length - 4] == DATA_CR && h[h.length - 3] == DATA_LF
                    && h[h.length - 2] == DATA_CR && h[h.length - 1] == DATA_LF)
                    && !(new String(this.remoteHandshake.array(), UTF8_CHARSET).contains("Sec"))
                    || (h.length == 23 && h[h.length - 1] == 0)) {
                _readHandshake(null);
             }else{
                _readHandshake(null);
            }
        }

        private void _readHandshake(byte[] handShakeBody) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
            // byte[] handshakeBytes = this.remoteHandshake.array();
            // String handshake = new String(handshakeBytes, UTF8_CHARSET);
            // TODO: Do some parsing of the returned handshake, and close connection
            // in received anything unexpected!

            this.handshakeComplete = true;
            boolean isConnectionReady = true;

            if (this.draft == WebSocket.Draft.DRAFT76) {
                if (handShakeBody == null) {
                    isConnectionReady = true;
                } else{
                byte[] challenge = new byte[] { (byte) (this.number1 >> 24), (byte) ((this.number1 << 8) >> 24),
                        (byte) ((this.number1 << 16) >> 24), (byte) ((this.number1 << 24) >> 24),
                        (byte) (this.number2 >> 24), (byte) ((this.number2 << 8) >> 24),
                        (byte) ((this.number2 << 16) >> 24), (byte) ((this.number2 << 24) >> 24), this.key3[0],
                        this.key3[1], this.key3[2], this.key3[3], this.key3[4], this.key3[5], this.key3[6], this.key3[7] };
                MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                byte[] expected = md5.digest(challenge);
                for (int i = 0; i < handShakeBody.length; i++) {
                    if (expected[i] != handShakeBody[i]) {
                        isConnectionReady = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isConnectionReady) {
                this.readyState = WEBSOCKET_STATE_OPEN;
                // fire onOpen method
                this.onOpen();
            } else {
                close();
            }
        }

        private String _randomKey() {
            Random r = new Random();
            long maxNumber = 4294967295L;
            long spaces = r.nextInt(12) + 1;
            int max = new Long(maxNumber / spaces).intValue();
            max = Math.abs(max);
            int number = r.nextInt(max) + 1;
            if (this.number1 == 0) {
                this.number1 = number;
            } else {
                this.number2 = number;
            }
            long product = number * spaces;
            String key = Long.toString(product);
            int numChars = r.nextInt(12);
            for (int i = 0; i < numChars; i++) {
                int position = r.nextInt(key.length());
                position = Math.abs(position);
                char randChar = (char) (r.nextInt(95) + 33);
                // exclude numbers here
                if (randChar >= 48 && randChar <= 57) {
                    randChar -= 15;
                }
                key = new StringBuilder(key).insert(position, randChar).toString();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
                int position = r.nextInt(key.length() - 1) + 1;
                position = Math.abs(position);
                key = new StringBuilder(key).insert(position, "\u0020").toString();
            }
            return key;
        }
    }
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    package com.example.test;

    import java.net.URI;
    import java.util.Random;


    import android.webkit.WebView;

    /**
     * The <tt>WebSocketFactory</tt> is like a helper class to instantiate new
     * WebSocket instaces especially from Javascript side. It expects a valid
     * "ws://" URI.
     * 
     * @author Animesh Kumar
     */
    public class WebSocketFactory {

        /** The app view. */
        WebView appView;

        /**
         * Instantiates a new web socket factory.
         * 
         * @param appView
         *            the app view
         */
        public WebSocketFactory(WebView appView) {
            this.appView = appView;
        }

        public WebSocket getInstance(String url) {
            // use Draft75 by default
            return getInstance(url, WebSocket.Draft.DRAFT76);
        }

        public WebSocket getInstance(String url, WebSocket.Draft draft) {
            WebSocket socket = null;

            Thread th = null;
            try {
                socket = new WebSocket(appView, new URI(url), draft, getRandonUniqueId());
                th = socket.connect();
                return socket;
            } catch (Exception e) {

                //Log.v("websocket", e.toString());
                if(th != null) {
                    th.interrupt();
                }
            } 
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Generates random unique ids for WebSocket instances
         * 
         * @return String
         */
        private String getRandonUniqueId() {
            return "WEBSOCKET." + new Random().nextInt(100);
        }

    }
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
            <title>Hello World</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="js/websocket.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               var socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.3:8101/');

        // push a message after the connection is established.
        socket.onopen = function() {

            socket.send('Hello World')
        };

        // alerts message pushed from server
        socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
            console.log("TTTTT"+JSON.stringify(msg));
        };

        // alert close event
        socket.onclose = function() {
            alert('closed');
        };
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

From the script I am calling my functions.

But when I check it on emulator it is showing that error.

Please help me removing this error.

Thanks.